# Get matched index value of array in MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using mongodb with java and my documents looks like :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("abcd1234rf54")
    createdDate: "12/11/15"
    type: 1
    nameIdentity: [
        {"name":"a"},
        {"name":"b"},
        {"name":"c"}
    ]
}
```

Where `nameIdentity` is an array of name documents. I am trying to query on name and find out index of matched document.
For eg: my query is  `Document resultDocument = mongoDatabase.getCollection(test).find(new Document("nameIdentity.name","b")).first();`.
 When this query is executed it gives me the result document/matched document. But what I also want is the index of the result document. I mean at what index there is a match. Is this possible in this approach or is there some other way to do so. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.